# Clear Form dropdowns and ckeditor control in asp.net

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net, ckeditor

I have a asp.net web page containing 5 to 6 dropdownlist and few texboxes along with CKEditor .net control in it.

I have a reset button and I am trying to clear the dropdownlist, textbox and ckeditor text on clicking it.

Below is my javascript to clear the form data

```js
function resetForm(){
  this.form.reset();
  //document.getElementById("frmNew").reset();
 }
```

This is the code to clear the ckEditor text

```js
        function resetCkEditor() {
            var myinstances = [];
            for (var i in CKEDITOR.instances) {
                CKEDITOR.instances[i].name;
                alert(CKEDITOR.instances[i].name);
                CKEDITOR.instances[i].updateElement();
                CKEDITOR.instances[i].setData('');
            }
        }
```

I tried to merge the two codes in a single function however only one is working. Either its resetting the form or its clearing the CKEditor. But I am not able to get all the things reset to its default.

Is there any way to do this? Any help will be highly appreciated.

Comment: @Yvette I tried that its not working. Also I tried to invoke one function from one button which triggers another button calling the second function. But that too didn't work. If I call each function in a separate button then it works perfectly.

Comment: @Yvette I need to clear both the form and ckeditor text in a single button click. I will be having only one RESET button.